# Simple Anomaly Detection Solution

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I have a few APIs that are called by clients. I collect data on them such as, what APIs they call, how often they call them etc. So, I have about 6 important metrics. I want to build an anomaly detection system around this. I have the following questions,

1) I want to build a simple model that can tell me if a new observation is an outlier based on the data I already have. Specifically, I am looking at implementing the low pass filter described in [datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection](http://datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection) post under the simple statistical methods section. Are there any drawbacks of implementing it this way?

The reason I ask about drawbacks is because I mostly see SVMs being used to solve such problems. I don't want to get fancy with it if I don't have to. Again, I don't care about predicting the new value, I just care about identifying if it doesn't correspond with *normal* behavior.

2) Can the 3-sigma limits method be used when there are multiple features? I have only seen it be used for univariate data. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303510/recommended-anomaly-detection-technique-for-simple-one-dimensional-scenario

If you all can also point to resources implementing similar problems, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "implementing it this way."  How exactly are you proposing to identify "outliers" or to determine "normal"?

Comment: @whuber I meant a low pass filter described in this https://www.datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection post under the simple statistical methods section.

Comment: I'm pretty sure few people would have guessed that: please edit your post so it clarifies what you're asking about.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is way too generic for a direct answer, I recommend you to look over PyOD Python library. It contains many outlier detection algorithms, but it is up to you and the particularities of your data to choose one. If you have collected some data which you know for sure contains only inliers, I think you can pick and test some Proximity-based algorithms first (they tend to be the most intuitive and easy to understand).

However, this is just a quick and naive way. If you need accuracy, I suggest you start off by analyzing your data set and then analyzing algorithms in order to find the one which fits your needs best.